# Send a POST request and receive a response using custom useFetch hook (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have used [this website](https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-fetch) to get the logic for a useFetch hook. All I am trying to do is to send a post request and then map the request into a type. I know this will be a simple answer but can't seem to find anything online! Please view the link above for the useFetch hook! :)

EDIT: The body is empty as this is just an example

Error: [View screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQrP.png)

Component:

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {},
  body: JSON.stringify({}),
};
const { data, error } = useFetch<ExampleType>({url, requestOptions});
```

Comment: Are there are errors?

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955250/how-to-use-custom-hook-fetch-with-typescript) post ?

Comment: @Papa yeah let me add them here

Comment: @JakubLicznerski that is a get request? No body sent too?

Comment: I believe you can pass same options to the generic `useFetch` that is described there

Comment: @Papa I have put error message in the question above

Comment: @Ben please always paste errors and code as text

Comment: Ignore last comment that did not seem to work!

Comment: I am stupid!!! Just noticed parameters have curly brackets!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UseFetch Documentation](https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-fetch) says you need to pass in a string as the first argument so call the hook with

```
useFetch<ExampleType>(url, requestOptions);
```